# Discrepancy in Measuring Execution Time of Concurrent Tasks

Tags: concurrency, clojure

The goal is to invoke a function concurrently (e.g., 10 times) and measure the total
execution time. However, I'm observing a significant discrepancy between the actual
time taken and the time reported by each thread. I've tried several approaches but I
am unable to resolve this discrepancy. I see this discrepancy while connecting
to one out of 2 servers (A and B) which makes me suspect that this issue has more to do
with how concurrent requests were being handled by server B, This is the behavior.

Across 10 threads

- Server A: Overall time: 200ms, Individual thread: ~80ms
- Server B: Overall time: ~2mins, Individual thread: ~2-10s

I am calculating the overall time manually because the start and end times of the
thread's don't convey the correct timings for Server B, which is what I am not
able to explain.

Here's a simplified version of the code

```clj
(defn- time-taken [f]
  (let [start (System/nanoTime)
        result (f)]
    [(- (System/nanoTime) start) result]))

(defn perform-task []
  ; 
  ; Invoke a REST API and some other code
  ; 
  :done)

(defn run-concurrent-tasks [n]
  (let [futures (mapv (fn [_] (future (time-taken perform-task))) (range n))]
    (mapv deref futures)))

(run-concurrent-tasks 10)
```

When I run `run-concurrent-tasks` the total elapsed time reported by each thread is much
lower (~1-2s) each whereas the actual overall time is around 2 mins (measured manually
outside the program).

At the moment I am running this code from the REPL and I can easily reproduce
the timing difference between Server A & B. I search for other posts but was
not able to find anything related to the problem I am facing.

**Questions:**

1. Why is there such a discrepancy between the actual time taken for the operation and the time reported by each thread, especially while connecting to one of the
   servers?
2. Is there a flaw in how I'm using `time-taken` or in the way I'm creating/using futures?
3. How can I accurately measure the total time taken for all concurrent tasks to complete?

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking to understand the root cause of this issue and how to correctly measure the execution time in such concurrent scenarios.

Comment: I see your edit, but you'll have to clarify how you're measuring, and what the difference is between A and B, if you think the agent pool isn't the issue. Nobody can really debug "a thing happens on one computer but not on another", without details on how to reproduce it.

Comment: I'll note one thing, though: your question 3 is easy to answer, and I expect will confirm that the future pool is the issue. Replace `(mapv deref futures)` with `(time-taken #(mapv deref futures))`. You should see that in fact all futures are ready quite quickly.

Comment: My recent edit has the timings for the same code connecting to 2 different servers

Comment: @amalloy, I am using the `time-taken` method for calculating the elapsed time. I am comparing this with a stop watch manual method because for Server B the execution time is much more than the reported time. 

This is not really the case of the same code working on one machine and not another. My code connects to 2 different servers with one performing better. The concern is that the client even though taking more time in one case is not reporting the time correctly. The results are correct in both cases.

Comment: I don't understand why this post is marked duplicate & closed. As mentioned in my post I haven't found any other posts where similar issues were faced. The questions at the beginning of the post are not related to the problem I am facing.